# Optimising MySQL Query, Select within Select, Multiple of same

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I need help optimising this MySQL statement that I whipped up. It does exactly what I want, however I have a great feeling that it'll be quite slow, since I do multiple selects within the statement, and I also query achievements_new multiple times. This is the first time I do some major statement like this, I'm used to the simple SELECT FROM WHERE style crap.

I might do some explaining, this is for a leaderboard style thing for my website.

--First variable output is a rank that is calculated according to the formula shown, (Log + Log + # of achievements).

--Wepvalue is the sum of the values of the weapons which that id has. **playerweapons** contains all the weapons, and **weaponprices** convert the type to the price, and then the SUM calculates the value.

--Achcount is simply the amount of achievements that's unlocked. *Maybe this can be optimised somehow with the rank output?*

--id in **achievements_new** and **playerweapons** are Foreign Keys to the id in **playerdata**

```
SELECT
    (
        IFNULL(LOG(1.5, cashearned),0) +
        IFNULL(LOG(1.3, roundswon), 0) +
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM achievements_new
            WHERE `value` = -1 AND achievements_new.id = playerdata.id
        )
    ) as rank,
    nationality,
    nick,
    steamid64,
    cash,
    playtime,
    damage,
    destroyed,
    (
        SELECT SUM(price)
        FROM weaponprices
        WHERE weapon IN
        (
            SELECT class
            FROM playerweapons
            WHERE playerweapons.id = playerdata.id
        )
    ) as wepvalue,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM achievements_new
        WHERE `value` = -1 AND achievements_new.id = playerdata.id
    ) as achcount,
    lastplayed
FROM playerdata
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Table structures:

**playerdata:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `playerdata` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `steamid64` char(17) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cash` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `playtime` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nationality` char(2) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `damage` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `destroyed` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cashearned` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `roundswon` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lastplayed` datetime NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**achievements_new:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `achievements_new` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `achkey` enum(<snip - lots of values here>) NOT NULL,
  `value` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**playerweapons:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `playerweapons` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**weaponprices:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `weaponprices` (
  `weapon` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

[image: Query Explain]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the explain also.That subquery with IN can be written as a JOIN.

Comment: Using JOINs instead of Sub queries will be a better option.

Comment: I'm aware of JOINS, just not how to use them properly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the query below.
I used `LEFT JOIN` instead of joins because there may be players without achievements or weapons. If you do not need these players you can use JOIN

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(LOG(1.5, p.cashearned),0) +
        IFNULL(LOG(1.3, p.roundswon), 0) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN ac.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(pw.id) as rank
    p.nationality,
    p.nick,
    p.steamid64,
    p.cash,
    p.playtime,
    p.damage,
    p.destroyed,
    --SUM(CASE WHEN pw.id IS NOT NULL THEN pw.price ELSE 0 END) as wepvalue,
    --wpn.price as wepvalue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pw.id IS NOT NULL THEN wp.price ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(ac.id) as wepvalue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ac.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(pw.id) as achcount,
    lastplayed
FROM playerdata as p
    JOIN playerweapons as pw ON pw.id = p.id
    JOIN weaponprices as wp ON pw.class = wp.weapon
    LEFT JOIN achievements_new as ac ON ac.id = p.id AND ac.value = -1
    --LEFT JOIN playerweapons as pw ON pw.id = p.id
    --LEFT JOIN weaponprices as wp ON pw.class = wp.weapon
    --LEFT JOIN (   SELECT 
                      --pw.id as player,
                      --SUM(wp.price) as price
                  --FROM weaponprices as wp
                      --JOIN playerweapons as pw ON pw.class = wp.weapon 
                  --GROUP BY pw.id
              --) as wpn ON wpn.player = p.id
GROUP BY 
    p.nationality,
    p.nick,
    p.steamid64,
    p.cash,
    p.playtime,
    p.damage,
    p.destroyed,
    p.lastplayed
```

Comment: It appears you missed out the "weaponprices" table entirely, otherwise this looks good!

Comment: Not sure why but my whole MySQL server froze up after calling this query, had to force restart it. :(

Comment: -scratch that-   It seems to cause extreme values on all sums, wepvalue is up to 10 millions where maximum possible is 315k. Achcount is up to the hundreds where maximum is 31.

Comment: Whenever you use aggregate functions like SUM, AVG or COUNT you need to use the [GROUP BY](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) clause.

Comment: That is happening because there can be multiple achievements and weapons for each player. Lets say a player has m weapons and n achievements then the weapons price will be n*m*price of each weapon. A solution would be to divide by the number of achievements. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fairly reasonable, although I would rewrite the subqueries to use explicit joins rather than `in` and factor out the achievements subquery:

```
SELECT (IFNULL(LOG(1.5, cashearned),0) + IFNULL(LOG(1.3, roundswon), 0) +
        coalesce(an.cnt, 0)
       ) as rank,
       nationality, nick, steamid64, cash, playtime, damage, destroyed,
       (SELECT SUM(wp.price)
        FROM weaponprices wp JOIN
             playerweapons pw
             on pw.class = wp.weapons
        WHERE pw.id = pd.id
       ) as wepvalue,
       coalesce(an.cnt, 0) as achcount,
       lastplayed
FROM playerdata pd left outer join
     (SELECT id, count(*) as cnt
      FROM achievements_new an
      WHERE an.`value` = -1 
      GROUP BY an.id
     ) an
     on an.id = pd.id
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

For this query, create the following indexes:

```
playerweapons(id, weapon);
weaponprices(class, price);
achievements_new(value, id);
```

This does the following things:

- It eliminates two redundant subqueries on `achievements_new`.
- It should optimize the prices subquery to only use indexes.
- It replaces the `in` with an explicit `join`, which is sometimes optimized better.
- It does not require an outer `group by`.

Comment: `on pw.weapon = wp.class` should read `on wp.weapon = pw.class` I believe. But for my curiosity: Why is this correlated subquery retained?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove all correlated subqueries

```
SELECT
      ( COALESCE(LOG(1.5, pd.cashearned), 0)
      + COALESCE(LOG(1.3, pd.roundswon), 0)
      + COALESCE(an.cnt, 0))   AS rank
    , pd.nationality
    , pd.nick
    , pd.steamid64
    , pd.cash
    , pd.playtime
    , pd.damage
    , pd.destroyed
    , COALESCE(pw.wepvalue, 0) AS wepvalue
    , COALESCE(an.cnt, 0)      AS achcount
    , pd.lastplayed
FROM playerdata pd
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        id
                      , COUNT(*) AS cnt
                  FROM achievements_new
                  WHERE value = -1
                  GROUP BY
                        id
            ) an
                  ON pd.id = an.id
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        playerweapons.id
                      , SUM(price) AS wepvalue
                  FROM weaponprices
                        INNER JOIN playerweapons
                                    ON weaponprices.weapon = playerweapons.class
                  GROUP BY
                        playerweapons.id
            ) pw
                  ON pd.id = pw.id
ORDER BY
      rank DESC;
```